# Access form / textbox default value problem

Tags: forms, ms-access, textbox

I have an access continous form:

[image]

I placed a unbound text box txt1 in the header where user enters the number of the assignment. I want all rows in the form to have the same assignement number - entered only once in the header. (Later, txt2 would be hidden).

In the form, i added a another textbox and placed default value as =[txt1].

My problem is that this text is being populated only in the second row, when i start typing in the first row.

As this:

[image]

Refreshing does not help.

Any ideas? 
Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I did a test and setting Textbox2 default value by expression in its DefaultValue property does not work when form opens because no value is available for the DefaultValue property. Refreshing does not trigger the DevaultValue property to reset but it does trigger when data entry initiated on new record row so it is then available for the next new record. Need to set property with VBA in some event procedure.

Use AfterUpdate event of Textbox1 before input is initiated for new record. That works.

Otherwise, input data directly into New Record row and use each control's AfterUpdate event to set its own DefaultValue property with that entered value. Subsequent records will populate with that value until user enters another and the DefaultValue will be reset.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , but it didnt work. I want all general information that is same for all records to be inserted in the header, that is why i need ro have unbounded text box in the header. Note: i have a similiar textbox near textbox1. Default value there is text “T”, and it works. The problem here is with the box where user enters data and it only applies to the second record. Refreshing and addin code to after update is not working. Is there a way to enable record entering after the textbox1 is populated

Comment: Wow, how did I not catch this comment 2 years ago!!! Revised answer.